# Nested cloud formation - Passing nested stack templates into main template

Tags: templates, amazon-web-services, nested, aws-cloudformation

I have a complicated template of over 3000+ lines.

main.json has:

```
     {
       "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
       "Parameters": {
               "param1": {
               },
               "param2": {
               },
       }
     },
        "mappings": {
         },
        "Resources": {
             "TemplateURL": "http://s3.aws.com/EC2_resource.json"
             "TemplateURL": "http://s3.aws.com/ECS_resource.json"
         }, 
         "Outputs": {
         }, 
         "Conditions": {
        }
     }

 EC2_resource.json
  {
     "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
     "Description": "RDS DBInstance",
     "Resources": {
          "EC2_resource":{
           }
       }
     } 
 }
```

I thought this might work. Not Sure what I'm doing wrong or what Im missing. I was following the guidelines provided in this github project
Here is a link:

[Link to github example](https://github.com/widdix/learn-cloudformation/tree/master/lab7-nested-stacks)

Let me thoughts. I am guessing what is described above might be wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put those template URLs in a Cloudformation stack type resource.  As described in this document : docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html

A very simple example : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-cloudformation.html#d0e17025